# Accessing controls within Property Sheet

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, propertysheet

I'm creating a Windows application using a PropertySheet (Wizard97 type), but I'm unclear how to access the controls from within the dialog callback.

First I setup the property sheet.

```
psp[1].dwSize = sizeof(PROPSHEETPAGE);
psp[1].dwFlags = PSP_HIDEHEADER ;
psp[1].hInstance = g_hInst;
psp[1].pszTemplate = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SETUP);
psp[1].pszIcon = NULL;
psp[1].pfnDlgProc = (DLGPROC)ButtonsDlgProc;
psp[1].lParam = 0;
```

So within the ButtonsDlgProc, I can't access the controls I've added to the dialog.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ButtonsDlgProc(HWND hdlg,
      UINT uMessage,
      WPARAM wParam,
      LPARAM lParam)
{
CButton * button;

switch (uMessage)
{
    case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (wParam)
    {
        case IDC_CHECK1:
            button = (CButton *)GetDlgItem(hdlg, IDC_CHECK1);
            button1IsChecked = button->GetCheck();
            break;
```

GetDlgItem returns a handle, but when invoking button->GetCheck(), I get an exception.  Is this the proper way to access control members?

Comment: `GetDlgItem(hdlg, IDC_CHECK1)` returns `HWND`, you cannot cast it to `CButton*`, they are two unrelated objects. If this was MFC's `CWnd::GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1)`, then you can cast `CWnd*` to `CButton*`. Or you can use `CWnd::Attach(HWND)` to attach a handle to `CButton*` - Anyway, I am confused about why you are mixing MFC with WinAPI like this. Please elaborate. Otherwise use `CPropertySheet` etc.

Comment: Good point.  I'm rather new to MFC, so I didn't realize I was mixing MFC and WinAPI.  I'll refactor to use CPropertySheet.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve it would be

```
button = (CButton *)CWnd::FromHandle(::GetDlgItem(hdlg, IDC_CHECK1));
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you.  I'm also going to try to refactor my code to use CPropertySheet.